# Ajax error function not working 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a search bar. The user should input the state and city. Once I get the state and city, update the html with the result. The problem is once i enter an invalid state or city, it gives me an error in the console. What i want is an alert telling the user that they have made a mistake in entering the city or state. I tried using a try and catch/ ajax error function but it doesn't seem to work. Need some help thanks !

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        $('h1').css('color','#222222');
    }, 3000);

    var search=  $('#search');
    var searchsubmit= $('#searchsubmit');

    searchsubmit.on('click', function(e){
        console.log(search.val());
        var searchresult= search.val();

        try {
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/69e8e728a8f8536f/geolookup/conditions/q/"+ searchresult +"/Cedar_Rapids.json",
                dataType : "jsonp",
                success : function(parsed_json) {
                    var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
                    var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
                    alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
                }
            });
        }catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: What's the error message? Please include it in your question

Comment: Probably not a good idea to include your API key in the question...

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding the error callback should work, here is a jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/ciwosoqeye/edit?html,js,output

```
    var searchresult = '';

    $.ajax({
    url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/69e8e728a8f8536f/geolookup/conditions/q/" +
        searchresult +"/Cedar_Rapids.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
        var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, errorString, ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
    });
```

as defined in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what error message you are getting or what `parsed_json` looks like with a bad request, this is only a guess but `parsed_json` probably doesn't have a `location` property and/or a `city` property when bad data is passed in. I'm guessing that is causing the error. If this is the case, you can check for the existence of `parsed_json.location` and `parsed_json.location.city` before trying to access them and display the error if they don't exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        $('h1').css('color','#222222');
    }, 3000);

    var search =  $('#search');
    var searchsubmit = $('#searchsubmit');

    searchsubmit.on('click', function(e){
        console.log(search.val());
        var searchresult= search.val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/69e8e728a8f8536f/geolookup/conditions/q/"+ searchresult +"/Cedar_Rapids.json",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(parsed_json) {
                if (parsed_json.location && parsed_json.location.city) {
                  var location = parsed_json.location.city;
                  var temp_f = parsed_json.current_observation.temp_f;
                  alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
                } else {
                  alert(err.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Setting a break-point at the beginning of the `success` callback and inspecting `parsed_data` would help in debugging this sort of thing.